# HTML-Css Adding column to the right of div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add some columns to the existing column and a row in HTML and CSS.

I tried copying `<div id=" gallery">` as it is, but its adding a column below the existing column

What I am trying to do is this

[image]

My existing code that i have written is

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Slideshow</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    body{margin: 0;padding: 0;font: 100% Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 14px;}
    div#gallery{border: 1px #ccc solid;width: 150px;margin: 40px auto;text-align: center;}
    div#gallery img{margin: 20px;border: 2px #004694 solid;}
    div#gallery p{color: #004694;}
    div#gallery div.pn{padding: 10px;margin: 0 5px;border-top: 1px #ccc solid;float: left;}
    a{color:#333;}
    a:hover{color:#cc0000;}
    a.sp{padding-right: 40px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="gallery">
    <div class="pn" >
            </div>
        <img src="56b0f76cf20f0_thumb900.jpg" width="100" alt="" />
        <p>test</p>
        <div class="pn">
            <img src="56b0f76cf20f0_thumb900.jpg" width="100" alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>.
    <div id="gallery">
    <div class="pn" >
            </div>
        <img src="56b0f76cf20f0_thumb900.jpg" width="100" alt="" />
        <p>test</p>
        <div class="pn">
            <img src="56b0f76cf20f0_thumb900.jpg" width="100" alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>.

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[see it on codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zqGZeV)

```
 <div id="gallery">
    <div class="pn">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/100x350">
        </div>

        <div class="pn">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x350">
        </div>
   <div class="pn">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x350">
        </div>
    </div>
```

here is the css

```
body{margin: 0;padding: 0;font: 100% Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 14px;}
    div#gallery{border: 1px #ccc solid;margin: 40px auto;text-align: center;}
    div#gallery img{margin: 20px;border: 2px #004694 solid;}
    div#gallery p{color: #004694;}
    div#gallery div.pn{padding: 10px;border-top: 1px #ccc solid; display:inline-block;width:33%;box-sizing:border-box}
    a{color:#333;}
    a:hover{color:#cc0000;}
    a.sp{padding-right: 40px;}
```

try tge above link. see if it works for you. you can use the same approach. keep your images 100% width instead of absolute pixel size

Answer (score 0):

If you add `float: left;` to the CSS of your `pn` class, your items should file in properly

Comment: I tried but now it looks like http://prnt.sc/aacsg3 i have updated the latest html in question

Comment: Can you post 56b0f76cf20f0_thumb900.jpg real quick?
Not necessary, just going to try to get the exact thing for ya

Comment: Is this what you're going for? https://s3.amazonaws.com/cerenity/SOResources/test.png